# Prove that $S=\{(x,y):|x+y|\leq 1, |xy|\leq 1\}$ is a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity, compactness

In my analysis test today, I was asked the question

> Prove that the set
> $$S=\{(x,y):|x+y|\leq 1, |xy|\leq 1\}$$
> is compact in $\mathbb R^2$.

Now, of course, to prove compactness, we need to show that $S$ is closed and bounded, and then use the Heine Borel Theorem. The bounded part is easy to show, since the set is contained in a ball of radius $2$. It was the closed part that sucked my blood out of me. I know that it's intuitively clear since the set contains the boundary. But, that's not an answer you write in your analysis test. What I did was to write
$$S=S_1\cap S_2$$
where
\begin{align*}
S_1&=\{(x,y):|x+y|\leq 1\}\\
S_2&=\{(x,y):|xy|\leq 1\}
\end{align*}
and then tried to prove that $S_1^\prime$ and $S_2^\prime$ are open (which proves that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are closed, and hence their intersection is closed). In the case of $S_1^\prime$, the distance between an arbitrary point and the lines $|x+y|\leq 1$ was easy to calculate explicitly; in the case of $S_2^\prime$, not really so.

Anyways, I feel, I wasn't rigorous enough, and there must be a neater way to solve this. Especially, I spent some time to find a continuous function $f$ such that the preimage of $f$ under some closed set is $S$, but couldn't find it. I'm quite sure, there must be a function which does the job.

Is there a better (than explicitly calculating distances) way to slove this?

Here's a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yjtgrsvcu9) of $S$, in case you are interested.

Comment: Set $$ f(x,y)= \vert x + y \vert,  g(x,y) = \vert x y \vert.$$ Both $f,g$ are continuous functions and we have $S_1 = f^{-1}([0,1]), S_2= g^{-1}([0,1])$.

Comment: Yes, I was actually thinking about finding a function, but after I broke it into the two intersections, I was time pressure and somehow missed it :|

Comment: Don't worry, that happens. The key thing is that you were thinking about using a function. This is an important trick to use in such situations. Next time you will know how to do it.

Comment: If $(x,y)\in S_1\cap S_2$ then $\big||x|-|y|\big|^2\leq |x-y|^2\leq 1$ and $2|xy|\leq 2$. Adding the terms each side of the inequalities yields $x^2+y^2=\big||x|-|y|\big|^2+ 2|xy|\leq 3$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz yes, but I don't understand what you tried to established

Comment: That $S_1\cap S_2\subset \overline{B}(\mathbf{0};\sqrt{3})=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 3\}$. Recall that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a set $A$ is bounded if there is an open ball $B(\mathbf{0};r)$ around the origin such that $A\subset B(\mathbf{0};r)$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz oh you mean the bounded part? yes, that's right.

Comment: Indeed. That $S_1\cap S_2$ is closed rather trivial as each $S_j=f_j^{-1}([0,1])$ for some continuous function $f_j$ that you can determined ($j=1,2$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ given by
$$
f(x,y) = (|x+y|,|xy|)
$$

is continuous as each component is continuous. We have
$$
S = f^{-1}([0,1] \times [0,1])
$$

so $S$ is the preimage of a closed set. Alternately you can also define $$
g(x,y) = (x+y,xy)
$$
which is continuous, and then $S = g^{-1}([-1,1] \times [-1,1])$. In either case, $S$ is closed. The boundedness of $S$ follows from the fact that for $(x,y)\in S$,
$$
x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2 - 2xy \leq |x+y|^2 + 2|xy| \leq 3
$$

and you are good. (I mean, you've already proved this, so this is just for completeness).

Comment: Ah yes! Nice! This one's really quite "compact" (+1)!

Comment: @SayanDutta Agreed, I'm not used to writing answers like this for some time, so just making sure I can help out if needed.

Comment: It;s quite fine. This was actualy the function I was looking for.  Actually, it's the first time we are dealing with multi-variable functions. That's why I missed it maybe.

Comment: @SayanDutta You can see the key advantage of multi-variable functions : it performs the "and" or the "intersection" operation, because two different components can capture two different kinds of bounds. For example, if you want to show that five or six sequences converge at once, then you can take a vector that contains these as components and prove that the vector itself converges. This is the great advantage of multi-variable calculus.

Comment: Yeah we had the same idea ... indicating this is the standard fast way ^^

Comment: @Teresa yes, just that I'm not very friendly (just a little familiar though) with them till now. I guess, I'll need some time to appreciate their essence fully. Your observation was quite nice though.

Comment: @LL3.14 Correct, thanks and +1 to you as well!

Answer (score 3):

$S=f^{-1}([0,1])\cap g^{-1}([0,1])$
where $g(x,y)=|x+y|$ and $f(x,y)=|xy|$,so it is closed as in intersection of closed sets..(the sets are closed because $f,g$ are continuous and we know that the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed)

Comment: Oh oops! I was thinking about finding a function, but after I broke it into the two intersections, I was time pressure and somehow missed it :|

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way might be to say that the function defined by
$$
f(x,y) = (|x+y|, |xy|)
$$
is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$ and so $S = f^{-1}([0,1]^2)$ is the inverse image of a closed set by a continuous function, hence is closed.

Comment: Yes, true. Actually, it's the first time we are dealing with multi-variable functions. That's why I missed it maybe.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to give here a different direction.

Among the 2 equations defining set $S$, the most restrictive is

$$|xy| \le 1 \implies ((|x| \le 1) \ \text{and} \ (|y| \le 1)) \implies x^2+y^2 \le 2$$

Therefore, $S$ is a **bounded** set (see figure below).

Besides, $S$ is a **closed** set (because it is defined as the intersection of 2 closed sets, this closedness coming from the definition by equations with $ \le$ signs).

Being bounded and closed, $S$ is a compact set.

[image]

Fig. 1:  Intersection set of a NW-SE stripe defined by $-1 \le x+y \le 1$ and the interior of hyperbola with equation $y=-\frac{1}{x}$ (the other hyperbola $y=\frac{1}{x}$ plays no rôle).

Comment: Yes, that's a correct and intuitive explanation of course (+1), and that's how you "guess" the answer. But, I can't write that in my analysis exam :(

Comment: If a student is able to produce this type of answer, even if there are still gaps and he/she is conscious of that as you are, he deserves the marks !

Comment: Unforyunately, that's not how math departments work :(

Answer (score 1):

Using the first approach, you don't need to explicitly calculate the distances, you just need to find a small enough neighborhood that is still contained in the set, using some bounds. Specifically, suppose that $|xy|=1 + \epsilon>1$. Then you will need to show that $|(x+\delta x)(y + \delta y)|>1$ if $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ are small enough. In particulat you can define some small $\gamma$ depending on $\epsilon$ such that if $\delta x^2 + \delta y^2 < \gamma$ then $|(x+\delta x)(y + \delta y)|>1$. A $\gamma$ that works in this case is $\gamma=\left(\min\left\{\frac{\epsilon}{1+|x| + |y|}, \frac12 \right\}\right)^2$, since $|\delta x|\le \sqrt{\gamma}$, $|\delta y|\le \sqrt{\gamma} \le \frac12$ and

$$\begin{aligned}
|(x+\delta x)(y + \delta y)|&\ge |xy| - |\delta x||y|-|\delta y||x| - |\delta x||\delta y|\ge |xy| - \sqrt{\gamma}\left(|y| + |x| + \frac12\right)\\&> 1 + \epsilon - \epsilon = 1
\end{aligned}$$

The second approach is easier though: the function $f(x,y) = |xy| - 1$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, that's also an answer (+1). It may not be neat, but it works.